# Clickable links in PDF are wrong on landscape pages (pdflscape + LuaLaTex)

Tags: hyperref, luatex, landscape, pdflscape

The hyperlinks in the PDF are not where they should be. It seems to be that glossary links are not "rotated" due to landscape mode. The following MWE illustrates the problem. The error occurs only in LuaLaTex. Everything works fine if I use  PDFLatex. Is this a bug or/and is there a workaround for this? I use TexLive 2013 with the latest updates installed.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage{pdflscape}
\usepackage[linkcolor=red]{hyperref}

\usepackage{glossaries}
\makeglossaries
\newacronym{PC}{PC}{Personal Computer}

\begin{document}

\begin{landscape}
  \mbox{\gls{PC}}
\end{landscape}

\gls{PC}
\clearpage
\printglossary

\end{document}
```

Link is wrong in LuaLaTex:

[image]

This is how it should look like (PDFLaTex):

[image]

**edit**

Links to the bibliography on a landscape page are also wrong. So this is probably a hyperref problem.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It is a bug in LuaTeX, see the tracker items [770](http://tracker.luatex.org/view.php?id=770) and [840](http://tracker.luatex.org/view.php?id=840).

Comment: Hmm, seems that Hans Hagen thinks the macro package is to blame: http://tracker.luatex.org/view.php?id=770#c1103

Comment: @Speravir: Thanks, I have answered with a [note](http://tracker.luatex.org/view.php?id=770#c1220) that contains a test file for iniTeX without macros.

Answer (score -1):

For Mac OS X users typesetting with Texpad/Texifier: use pdfLaTeX to typeset instead of the built-in typesetter. This causes the same issue.